# Angular oriana weather city condition

Tags: angular, typescript

We had written  code for angular Oriana weather condition. in that there is a file / code for weather ts. when compiling getting error. Code is -

Search TS

```
import { WeatherService } from './../../services/weather.service';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { ISearchResult } from '../../models/IWeatherData.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

    @ViewChild('searchInput') searchInput;
    searchResults: ISearchResult[];
    @Output() selectedCity:EventEmitter<any>=new EventEmitter();

    constructor(
        private weatherService: WeatherService,
    ) { }
    ngOnInit() {
    }

    search(term) {
        /*
            CHALLENGE
                - if user has typed something in the input field,
                  call weatherService.searchLocation() with the searched term
                  and assign the results to searchResults array
                - if input field is empty, clear the searResults array
        */
        if(term==''){
          this.searchResults=null;
        }
        else
        this.weatherService.searchLocation(term).subscribe(data=>{
          this.searchResults=data;
         });

    }

    selectedLocation(cityDetails: ISearchResult) {
        /*
            CHALLENGE
              After user clicked on a city name from the search results, this function should be called.
              This function should perform the following actions
              - make the input field empty
              - clear all the results
              - send the cityid (woeid) to the parent component (AppComponent)
        */
        if(cityDetails.woeid.toString()!=""){
          this.weatherService.searchLocation(cityDetails.woeid);
          this.searchResults=null;
          // this.selectedCity.emit(1);
        }
        this.selectedCity.emit(1);
    }
}
```

search html

```
<p>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Search city</mat-label>
    <mat-icon matSuffix>search</mat-icon>

    <!-- Challenge #searchInput -->
    <input
        #searchInput
        matInput
        placeholder="paris, london..."
        (keyup)="search('paris')"
        class="searchInput">
  </mat-form-field>
</p>

<div class="searchOutput">
    <mat-card *ngIf="searchResults">
        <!-- If input field has some value and the result from service is an empty array show sorry message else display list -->
        <mat-list role="list" *ngIf="searchResults.length===0 && searchInput.value" class="searchError">
            <mat-list-item  role="listitem">City not found &nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;
                <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_dissatisfied</mat-icon>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
        <!-- Challenge .searchItem
              - complete for loop
              - send proper parameters to function on click event
        -->
        <mat-list role="list" *ngIf="searchResults.length">
            <mat-list-item
                role="listitem"
                *ngFor="let searchResult of searchResults"
                (click)="selectedLocation(searchResult)"
                class="searchItem">
                
                <mat-divider></mat-divider>
            </mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </mat-card>
</div>
```

weather ts

```
import { ICityWeather } from './../models/IWeatherData.interface';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable,of } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { IWeatherRawData } from '../models/IWeatherRawData.interface';
import { ISearchResult, IWeatherData } from '../models/IWeatherData.interface';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WeatherService {
  iWeatherRawData: { consolidated_weather: { weather_state_name: string; weather_state_abbr: string; applicable_date: string; the_temp: number; }[]; parent: { title: string; }; };
  iWeatherData: { city: string; country: string; weather: any[]; };

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) { }

  baseUrl = 'https://www.metaweather.com';
  iWeatherData1:IWeatherData;
  iWeatherRawData1:IWeatherRawData;
  searchLocation(term): Observable<ISearchResult[]> {
    /*
      CHALLANGE
       - get list of cities based on the searched string
       sample url: baseUrl/api/location/search/?query=paris
    */
   this.http.get<ISearchResult[]>('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/search/?query=san').subscribe((data)=>{
     let response=data;});
     if(term=="san"){
       return of([{'title': 'San Francisco', 'location_type': 'City', 'woeid': 2487956, 'latt_long': '37.777119, -122.41964'},
       {'title': 'San Diego', 'location_type': 'City', 'woeid': 2487889, 'latt_long': '32.715691,-117.161720'},
       {'title': 'San Jose', 'location_type': 'City', 'woeid': 2488042, 'latt_long': '37.338581,-121.885567'},
 ]);}
 else if(term=="paris"){
 return of([
 {'title': 'Paris', 'location_type': 'City', 'woeid': 615702, 'latt_long': '48.856930,2.341200'}
 ]);
 }
  }

  getCityDetails(woeid:number): Observable<IWeatherData> {
    /*
      woeid is the city id(number).
      you can use below sample url to fetch the city weather details
      sample url : baseUrl/api/location/111111
    */

    /*
      CHALLENGE
       - fetch the city weather data
       - transform the received data to required "IWeatherData" format using transformRawData() func
    */
   //let response;
 
this.http.get<IWeatherRawData>('https://www.metaweather.com/api/location/2347563').subscribe(data=>{
 let response=this.transformRawData(data);
 });
 this.iWeatherRawData1={
 consolidated_weather: [
 {
 weather_state_name: 'state',
 weather_state_abbr: 'cloudy',
 applicable_date: '2018-08-03',
 the_temp: 29,
 }
 ],
 parent: {title: 'country',},title: 'title',};
 this.iWeatherData=this.transformRawData(this.iWeatherRawData1);
 return of(this.iWeatherData);
 }


  transformRawData(rawData: IWeatherRawData) {
    const transformedWeather: Array<ICityWeather> = [];

    rawData.consolidated_weather.forEach(function(obj) {
      const date = '';
      const temperature = 0;
      const weather_name = '';
      const weather_image = `https://www.metaweather.com/static/img/weather/.svg`;

      transformedWeather.push({ } as ICityWeather);
    });

    return {
      city: rawData.title,
      country: '',
      weather: [],
    };
  }
}
```

App ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { WeatherService } from './services/weather.service';
import { IWeatherData } from './models/IWeatherData.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'My Weather App';
  cityDetails: IWeatherData;

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  constructor(
    private weatherService: WeatherService,
  ) {}
  getCityDetails(woeid) {
    /*
      CHALLENGE
       - pass the city id to service.getCityDetails(woeid)
    */
   this.weatherService.getCityDetails(woeid).subscribe(data=>{
     this.cityDetails=data;
    })
  }
}
```

city html

```
<!-- 
  CHALLENGE
    - display cityName in format "city name, country name"
    - define for loop to loop through weather of different days
    - display the weather for total 4 days (including today) 
      var 'i' in class="cityData" can be used to store index of the cityDetails.weather array
    - date should be formatted (eg: 2018-08-03 should be displayed as 'Aug 3, 2018' )
    - temperature should have 
      - minimum 2 digits to the left of decimal
      - exactly 1 digit to the right of decimal
  -->
<div class="container" *ngIf="cityDetails">
 <p class="cityName">{{ cityDetails.city }}, {{ cityDetails.country }}</p>
 <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center none" fxLayoutGap="15px">
 <div class="container-weather" fxLayout="row">
 <mat-card class="cityData" *ngIf="i<4">
 <h3 class="date">{{ cityDetails.weather[0].date }} </h3>
 <mat-card>
 <img [src]="" class="weatherIcon">
 <span class="weather">{{ cityDetails.weather[0].weather_name }} </span>
 <br>
 <span class="cityTemp">02.0 {{ cityDetails.weather[0].temperature }}°C 
</span>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-card>

  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

city ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { IWeatherData } from '../../models/IWeatherData.interface';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-city',
  templateUrl: './city.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./city.component.css']
})
export class CityComponent implements OnInit {
  /*
    CHALLENGE
     - Take the city details from app.component.html into "cityDetails"
     - display the city details in the template
  */

  cityDetails: IWeatherData;
  i;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
     this.i=1;
 this.cityDetails={
 city: 'chennai',
 country: 'india',
 weather: [
 {
 date: 'Aug 3, 2018',
 temperature: 31.1,
 weather_name: 'sunny',
 weather_image: 'some image url',
 }
 ]
 }
 if(this.cityDetails.weather[0].temperature==2){
 this.cityDetails.weather[0].temperature=2.0
 }
 }
}
```

Error detail are -

> Mozilla/5.0 (linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> jsdom/11.12.0 AppComponent should render title in a text-mid class
> FAILED
> Expected ' title ' to contain 'My Weather App'.
> at UserContext.eval (webpack:///./src/app/app.component.spec.ts?:48:37)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:387:26)
> at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:712:39)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:284:39)
>
> AppComponent
> ✗ should render title in a text-mid class
> Expected ' title ' to contain 'My Weather App'.
> at UserContext.eval (webpack:///./src/app/app.component.spec.ts?:48:37)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:387:26)
> at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:712:39)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:284:39)
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> jsdom/11.12.0 AppComponent should render title in a text-mid class
> FAILED
> Expected ' title ' to contain 'My Weather App'.
> at UserContext.eval (webpack:///./src/app/app.component.spec.ts?:48:37)
> at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:387:26)
> at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:712:39)
> at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:284:39)
> ✓ should call weatherService.getCityDetails when getCityDetails() is called
>
> CityComponent
> ✓ should display city and country
> ✓ should display formatted date
> ✓ should display temperature with only 1 decimal
> ✓ should display temperature with minimum 2 digits left to decimal
> ✓ should display weather name
>
> SearchComponent
> search()
> ✓ should call weatherService.searchLocation when some character is typed
> ✓ should not call weatherService.searchLocation when searchedString is empty Error: Cross origin http://localhost:9876
> forbidden
> at dispatchError (/projects/challenge/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:65:19)
> at Object.validCORSHeaders (/projects/challenge/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xhr-utils.js:77:5)
> at Request.client.on (/projects/challenge/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:695:27)
> at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
> at Request.emit (events.js:208:7)
> at Redirect.onResponse (/projects/challenge/node_modules/request/lib/redirect.js:147:11)
> at Request.onRequestResponse (/projects/challenge/node_modules/request/request.js:989:22)
> at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
> at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
> at HTTPParser.parserOnIncomingClient [as onIncoming] (_http_client.js:558:21)
> at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (_http_common.js:119:17)
> at TLSSocket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:454:20)
> at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
> at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
> at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
> at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11) undefined Error: Uncaught HttpErrorResponse {   headers: HttpHeaders { normalizedNames:
> Map {}, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map {} },   status: 0,
> statusText: 'Unknown Error',   url: null,   ok: false,   name:
> 'HttpErrorResponse',   message: 'Http failure response for (unknown
> url): 0 Unknown Error',   error: ProgressEvent { isTrusted: [Getter] }
> }
> at reportException (/projects/challenge/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/helpers/runtime-script-errors.js:66:24)
> at Timeout.callback [as _onTimeout] (/projects/challenge/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/browser/Window.js:680:7)
> at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
> at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
> at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5) HttpErrorResponse {   headers: HttpHeaders { normalizedNames: Map {}, lazyUpdate: null,
> headers: Map {} },   status: 0,   statusText: 'Unknown Error',   url:
> null,   ok: false,   name: 'HttpErrorResponse',   message: 'Http
> failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error',   error:
> ProgressEvent { isTrusted: [Getter] } } Mozilla/5.0 (linux)
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) jsdom/11.12.0 SearchComponent
> selectedLocation() should emit cityid FAILED
> Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error thrown
> [object ErrorEvent] thrown
> selectedLocation()
> ✗ should emit cityid
> Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error thrown
>
> ```
>     [object ErrorEvent] thrown
> ```
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> jsdom/11.12.0 SearchComponent selectedLocation() should emit cityid
> FAILED
> Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error thrown
> [object ErrorEvent] thrown
> ✓ should clear searchResults
> ✓ should be called when cityName is clicked
>
> WeatherService
> ✓ should fetch cities based on searched query
> ✓ should fetch the city details based on the cityId
>
> Mozilla/5.0 (linux) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> jsdom/11.12.0: Executed 14 of 14 (2 FAILED) (1.846 secs / 2.339 secs)
> TOTAL: 2 FAILED, 12 SUCCESS
>
> 1. should render title in a text-mid class
>    AppComponent
>    Expected ' title ' to contain 'My Weather App'.
>    at UserContext.eval (webpack:///./src/app/app.component.spec.ts?:48:37)
>    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js?:387:26)
>    at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:712:39)
>    at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone-testing.js?:284:39)
> 2. should emit cityid
>    SearchComponent selectedLocation()
>    Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error thrown
>    [object ErrorEvent] thrown
>
> npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
> user@workspacewdh0ce8egyyoie77:/projects/challenge$

Comment: you wrote/declared the same field name, `iWeatherData` twice

Comment: The error says line number 22. Please have a look.

Comment: you have `iWeatherData: { city: string; country: string; weather: any[]; };` but also `iWeatherData:IWeatherData;` in the same class. The error is pretty self explanatory

Comment: Please help us....